# Friendly URL rewrite rules for query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to rewrite htaccess to accept query string for SEO friendly,

The old method that I used to passing parameters through url is:

```
http://sitename.com/foldername/edit-agent.php?name=John-Smith
```

I wanted to change above url to:

```
http://sitename.com/foldername/edit-agent/John-Smith
```

my htaccess file rule is as follow:

```
<files page>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^edit-agent/([^/\.]+)/?$ edit-agent.php?name=$1 [L]


#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

to get the passing parameter, in `edit-agent.php` file, I use:

```
$agent_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
```

When I got to url `http://sitename.com/foldername/edit-agent/John-Smith`, the page is show **Internal Server Error**

any clue on this matter?

Comment: haven't you missed "foldername" from your rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep this code in `/foldername/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^edit-agent/([^/.]+)/?$ edit-agent.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` will prevent rewrite rules to execute more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule (.*)/ edit-agent.php?name=$1
```